# Edit the contents list of TableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController` with lists of data entry using `CoreData`. I also have `ViewController` with `UITextView` as linked by Segue to `TableViewController`. I have completed operations like add, save and delete on items.

Now I am working on edit by linking the selected `TableViewCell` to `UITextView` on next `ViewController`.I have created an action DONE on `ViewController.I` am able to pass data from selected Cell to TextView of next `ViewController` using Segue.

Now, I need to update the edited text on `UITextView` by clicking DONE button to back to Cells of `TableViewController` and also save data to `CoreData`. Plzz give the genuine advices and suggestions....I am new to Swift and I have enclosed my code here.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ToDoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var listItems = [NSManagedObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add, target: self , action: #selector(ToDoTableViewController.addItem))
}

func addItem(){
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "To Do Tasks Lists!!!!", message: "Write Down...", preferredStyle: .alert)
let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: ({
    (_) in
    if let field = alertController.textFields![0] as? UITextField {
        self.saveItem(itemToSave: (field.text!))
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    }
))

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: ({
    (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Type in Something!!!!"
}))

alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func saveItem(itemToSave : String){
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ListEntity", in: managedContext)
let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
item.setValue(itemToSave, forKey: "item")
do {
    try managedContext.save()
    listItems.append(item)
}
catch {

    print("Error")
}
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ListEntity")

do{
    let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    listItems = results as! [NSManagedObject]
}
catch {
    print("Error")
}
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if editingStyle == .delete {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let objectToDelete = listItems[indexPath.row]
    listItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    managedContext.delete(objectToDelete)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return listItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell
let item = listItems[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = item.value(forKey: "item") as! String?
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
return cell
}

func getIndexPathForSelectedCell() -> IndexPath?
{
var indexPath2:IndexPath?
if tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!.count > 0 {
    indexPath2 = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows![0]
}
return indexPath2
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if (segue.identifier == "detailView")
{
    if let indexPath2 = getIndexPathForSelectedCell()
    {
        // here write code for move to next controller.
        let vc = segue.destination as! TextEditViewController
        //vc.FirstString =  listItems[(indexPath2 as NSIndexPath).row] as String

        let item = listItems[(indexPath2 as NSIndexPath).row]
        vc.FirstString = (item.value(forKey: "item") as! String?)!
    }
}
}

}


//TextEditViewController
import UIKit
import CoreData
class TextEditViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var textEdit: UITextView!
var FirstString = String()    

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
textEdit.text = FirstString
print(self.FirstString)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: print item data & put debug there and check it

Comment: Himanshu Moradiya @ U don't have any idea ,,,... U are here just for bait for upvotes and approval. U didn't solve my issue before !!

Comment: Do you want to update your text in coredata after editing on secondVC and shown it to tableview which is on FirstVC?

Comment: Yepp Sir.... Plzzz help me ... I have written everything up there @ Dheeraj D

Comment: @AngelKajol check my answer that i give you simple logic of how to work with core data in your case.

Comment: @Angel just see below answer and let me know if have any other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your CoreData model reference to next screen:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if (segue.identifier == "detailView")
{
    if let indexPath2 = getIndexPathForSelectedCell()
    {
        // here write code for move to next controller.
        let vc = segue.destination as! TextEditViewController
        //vc.FirstString =  listItems[(indexPath2 as NSIndexPath).row] as String
        let item = listItems[(indexPath2 as NSIndexPath).row]
        vc.FirstString = (item.value(forKey: "item") as! String?)!
        vc.recentItem = item; //Like this. Create a recentItem refrence to your next controller of NSManagedObject or your custom core data modal.
    }
}
}
```

When you are done with your editing in `TextEditViewController`:

```
recentItem.item = "String" //Your updated string

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
do {
        try managedContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }
```

Hope this will work...!!

Comment: where shall i add this Sir ??                                                                                                                                         recentItem.item = "String" //Your updated string
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
do {
        try managedContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }                                                                                                                     If U wish Can edit the question I asked.  @ Dheeraj D

Comment: In your TextViewController write recent.item = string when you done with editing. and all remaning code in Done button action

Comment: let me check and will revert you